# IndexOutOfBoundsExeption in my adapter

Tags: java, android, android-listview, bitmap, android-arrayadapter

In my ArrayAdapter i get this error in logcat:

```
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863): Process: it.rs.esempioparsinglistview, PID: 10863
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at it.rs.esempioparsinglistview.ParsingArrayAdapter.getView(ParsingArrayAdapter.java:80)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16504)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16504)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16504)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16504)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2552)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16504)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
01-21 18:34:21.705: E/AndroidRuntime(10863):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
```

the line 80 is this:

```
cache.immagini.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(pos));
```

in the getView:

```
public View getView(int pos,View view,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CacheRiga cache; //cache
        if(view==null)//se è la prima volta che viene richiesta la view
        {
            // creo la view ma non l'attacco alla lista in quanto devo ancora modificare
            // i testi delle textview
            view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, parent,false); 
            cache = new CacheRiga(); //inizializzo la cache
            cache.titolo = (TextView) view.findViewById(TITOLO); //collego titolo

            cache.immagini = (ImageView) view.findViewById(IMMAGINE);//collego descrizione


            view.setTag(cache);//collego view con cache
        }
        else
        {
            cache = (CacheRiga) view.getTag(); //altrimenti prendo la cache dalla view
        }

        cache.titolo.setText(titoli.get(pos)); //set the title

        cache.immagini.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(pos)); //set the image


        if (bitmap!=null){
            Log.d("Bitmap MP.it", "BitmapNOTnull");         
        }else{
            Log.d("Bitmap null MP.it", "Bitmapnull");    
        }
        return view;
    }
```

infact, if i comment that line i don't get the error but i can't display the images in the list.. Why this error? how can i do to insert the bitmap in the list?

FULL ADAPTER

```
public class ParsingArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    //riferimenti statici alle risorse e agli id
    private final static int LAYOUT = R.layout.riga_listview;
    private final static int TITOLO = R.id.riga_listview_titolo;
    private final static int IMMAGINE = R.id.imageView1;

    List<Bitmap> bitmap ; 

    ArrayList<String> titoli; //lista dei titoli

    Context c; //context
    LayoutInflater inflater; //layout inflater


    public ParsingArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> titoli, List<Bitmap> bitmap)
    {
        super(context,TITOLO);
        this.c = context;
        this.titoli = titoli;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return titoli.size(); //ritorno lunghezza lista ( = numero dei titoli)
    }

    //quando la lista richiede una view
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos,View view,ViewGroup parent)
    {
        CacheRiga cache; //cache
        if(view==null)//se è la prima volta che viene richiesta la view
        {
            // creo la view ma non l'attacco alla lista in quanto devo ancora modificare
            // i testi delle textview
            view = inflater.inflate(LAYOUT, parent,false); 
            cache = new CacheRiga(); //inizializzo la cache
            cache.titolo = (TextView) view.findViewById(TITOLO); //collego titolo

            cache.immagini = (ImageView) view.findViewById(IMMAGINE);//collego descrizione


            view.setTag(cache);//collego view con cache
        }
        else
        {
            cache = (CacheRiga) view.getTag(); //altrimenti prendo la cache dalla view
        }

        cache.titolo.setText(titoli.get(pos)); //imposto il titolo

        cache.immagini.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(pos));


        if (bitmap!=null){
            Log.d("Bitmap MP.it", "BitmapNOTnull");         
        }else{
            Log.d("Bitmap null MP.it", "Bitmapnull");    
        }
        return view;
    }

    private class CacheRiga { // classe per la cache delle righe
        public TextView titolo; // cache titolo
        public ImageView immagini; // cache images
    }

}
```

MAINACTIVITY:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    public static final String TAG_TITOLI = "titoli";
    private static final String TAG_IMMAGINE = "immagine";
    ListView lista;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    public ImageView immagine;
    public ImageView logoimg;

    static final String BLOG_URL = "http://www.multiplayer.it";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        lista = (ListView)this.findViewById(R.id.main_lista);//recupero lista da id



        //View inflatedView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.riga_listview, null);
        //immaginebtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.immaginebtn);
        //creo ed eseguo l'asynctask
        ParsingPaginaWeb parsing = new ParsingPaginaWeb();
        parsing.execute("");

        // Immagine btn
        /*immaginebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // Execute Logo AsyncTask
                new Logo().execute();
            }
        });*/
        //new Logo().execute();

         // Launching new screen on Selecting Single ListItem
            lista.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    // getting values from selected ListItem
                    String titoli = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.riga_listview_titolo)).getText().toString();
                    immagine = ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView1));

                    // Starting new intent
                    Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleActivity.class);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_TITOLI, titoli);
                    in.putExtra(TAG_IMMAGINE, bitmap);
                    //in.putExtra(TAG_CONTENT, cont);
                    startActivity(in);

                }
            });

    }

    private class ParsingPaginaWeb extends AsyncTask<String,String,String> {

        ArrayList<String> titoli; //lista dei titoli
        ArrayList<Bitmap> bitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(); 
        //ArrayList<String> content; //lista delle descrizioni

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute()
        {   
            //prima di eseguire il parsing inizializzo gli arraylist
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Multiplayer.it");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Caricamento articoli...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();

            titoli = new ArrayList<String>();
            bitmap = new ArrayList<Bitmap>(); 
            //content = new ArrayList<String>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                Document doc = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
                Elements nodeBlogStats = doc.select("div.news-col-0 h3"); //per multiplayer.it Elements nodeBlogStats = doc.select("div.news-col-0 h3"); per ftv #comunePartINI > option
                for(Element sezione : nodeBlogStats)
                {
                    titoli.add(sezione.text());



                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // In caso di errore
                Log.e("ESEMPIO", "ERRORE NEL PARSING");
            }
            return null;
        }



        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result)
        {
            // dopo che ho eseguito il parsing mostro i dati nella listview
            // usando il custom array adpater ParsingArrayAdapter
            ParsingArrayAdapter adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, titoli, bitmap);
            lista.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
            new Logo().execute();
        }


    }

    // Classe per caricamento immagini..

    // Logo AsyncTask

    private class Logo extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Immagini");
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading images...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            try {
                // Connect to the web site
                Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
                // Using Elements to get the class data 
                //Elements img = document.select("div.news-col-0 img[src]");
                // Locate the src attribute
                for(Element img : document.select("div.news-col-0 img[src]")) {
                    String ImgSrc = img.attr("src");
                // Download image from URL
                    InputStream is = new java.net.URL(ImgSrc).openStream();
                    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // Set downloaded image into ImageView
            logoimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            logoimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();

           // ParsingArrayAdapter adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, titoli);
           // lista.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show your full adapter class?

Comment: Well it looks like `bitmap` is empty. You need to work out why. We don't have any information about that.

Comment: if i remove that line the log says: `BitmapNOTnull` so i don't understand!

Comment: @End.Game is the size of `titoli` and `bitmap` same?

Comment: It seems that your ArrayList is empty.

Comment: How can i check it? how can i make the same size?

Comment: @End.Game you need to check at the place where you populate both lists

Comment: here in the adapter you mean?

Comment: @End.Game no where you add items to your list.

Comment: Ah ok in my MainActivity.. Can i update the question with the MainActivity so you can check if there are mistakes? Please

Comment: @Raghunandan i logged and the debug says: `01-21 18:55:41.735: D/Array compare(12551): Titoli > Bitmap!
` How can i do now? Want the MainActivity?

Comment: @End.Game you are not populating bitmap list anywhere in your code hence the size is 0.

Comment: And how can i solve? How is possible is null?

Comment: i can't understand if the problem is in the adapter or in the MainActivity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not adding bitmaps to your ArrayList. I think in your Logo AsyncTask, in doInBackground, instead of:

```
for(Element img : document.select("div.news-col-0 img[src]")) {
    String ImgSrc = img.attr("src");
    // Download image from URL
    InputStream is = new java.net.URL(ImgSrc).openStream();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
 }
```

you want to do:

```
 for(Element img : document.select("div.news-col-0 img[src]")) {
    String ImgSrc = img.attr("src");
    // Download image from URL
    InputStream is = new java.net.URL(ImgSrc).openStream();

    //add Bitmap to an array
    bitmap.add(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is));
 }
```

Comment: you're right i think.. but in `add` i get this syntax error: `The method add(Bitmap) is undefined for the type Bitmap`

Comment: It's because your global bitmap in your MainActivity is of type Bitmap - change it to List<Bitmap>.

Comment: have i to leave `new Logo().execute();` in onPostExecute?

Comment: Actually, in onPostExecute, you are creating ParsingArrayAdapter with titoli and bitmap objects as arguments, but your bitmap is still empty. Keep new Logo().execute() and move ParsingArrayAdapter adapter = new ParsingArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this, titoli, bitmap); lista.setAdapter(adapter); to onPostExecute in Logo.

Comment: here: `logoimg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            logoimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` in `setImageBitmap`i have this now : `The method setImageBitmap(Bitmap) in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<Bitmap>)` :(

Comment: Of course, setImageView expects a Bitmap, and you're passing ArrayList<Bitmap>. What is the image that should be set here? You can use one from ArrayList<Bitmap>, eg. logoimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(0)); but I'm not sure which one you want.

Comment: well i need pass the first image for the first article, second image for second article etc etc...

Comment: if i write `logoimg.setImageBitmap(bitmap.get(0));` what i'm going to take?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45755/discussion-between-end-game-and-melquiades)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your bitmap array is too small (but not null).

Please, check that bitmap array have equal or greater items than titoli array.
For example:

```
public ParsingArrayAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> titoli, List<Bitmap> bitmap)
    {
        super(context,TITOLO);
        this.c = context;
        this.titoli = titoli;
        this.bitmap = bitmap;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        if (this.titoli.size() > this.bitmap.size())
        Log.d("Array compare", "Titoli > Bitmap!");  
    }
```

and check log output

Comment: how can i check it? thinking about it i don't know if are the same size.. How can i do?

Comment: Ok it returns `01-21 18:55:41.735: D/Array compare(12551): Titoli > Bitmap!
` so what do you suggest to do?

Comment: In your adapter you fill custom view for each item in titoli. Also, for each view you load image from bitmap array. If your bitmap array is less that titoli, app crashes whn bitmap array ends.
You can do not use bitmap array or check why it less that titoli (as I think these both arrays fills in your activity code)

Comment: @End.Game where do you add items to list. check there

Comment: done, i tried also see the size of titoli and bitmap.. `titoli = 60` and `bitmap = 0` :(